# Understanding the nop byte(s)

Tags: 64-bit, x86, cpu-architecture, assembly

Ok, so I was reading through the AMD64 manuels and knowing that `nop` is really an `xchg eax, eax`, I looked at the `xchg` and found something interesting, that it seems a byte can be encoded into the instruction for specifying the registers (apologies I'm on my iPod): [picture](http://db.tt/kUVRMSWK).

So what I am wondering is how does the processor know if there is a byte after to work with or is it that that extra register has to be of type `rAX` causing it to actually still be the one byte `0x90`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I looked at the xchg and found something interesting, that it seems a
>   byte can be encoded into the instruction for specifying the registers

Yes, that's how most x86 instructions work.  Instructions are fetched either 32 or 64 bits at a time (word length of the machine), not bytes at a time.

Specifying an `XCHG` of `rAX` with `rAX` (where `rAX` is `EAX` on a 32-bit machine, and `RAX` on a 64-bit machine) will be `0x90`, because the register mux code for `rAX` is `0x00` (effectively a one cycle operation which does doing nothing).  Similarly, the instruction `XCHG rBX, rAX` will assemble to `0x93` (the mux code of `rBX` being `0b011`).

The opcode encoding should be listed somewhere else in the manual, or you can look on an x86 opcode map (which helps to understand how everything is muxed together).  You can find one in the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm) (Volume 2, Appendix A.3).

> So what I am wondering is how does the processor know if there is a
>   byte after to work with or is it that that extra register has to be of
>   type rAX causing it to actually still be the one byte 0x90

Here, it's the opposite.  For 64-bit mode, there is actually a *prefix* in the instruction word itself to indicate that (`REX` prefix).  The processor knows what to look for based on the presence or absence of the `REX` prefix - and in the absence of, the instruction is still just `0x90`.